# How to format date in Laravel 5.8 From "Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200" to MySQL format?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm  working on the backend for an App for school and I got a problem converting a date that I get from a request like "Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200" to MySQL format (timestamp).

```
public function getAll(Request $request){
        $start = $request->input('start');
        $end = $request->input('end');

        // we receive some thing like:
        // Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
        $sales = Sale::with('SaleLine.lens','SaleLine.cadre','cli_sale')
                    ->whereBetween('created_a', [$start, $end])
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        for ($i=0; $i < count($sales); $i++) {
            $sales[$i]['client_name'] = $sales[$i]['cli_sale']['first_name'] . " " . $sales[$i]['cli_sale']['last_name'];
        }
        return response()->success(['sales'=>$sales]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Carbon::parse()` and get it like

```
>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse('Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200')
    => Carbon\Carbon @1554933600 {#3119
         date: 2019-04-11 00:00:00.0 +02:00,
       }
>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse('Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200')->toDateTimeString(
);
=> "2019-04-11 00:00:00"
```

Rewriting your code will be

```
public function getAll(Request $request){
        $start = $request->input('start');
        $end = $request->input('end');
        $start = Carbon\Carbon::parse($start)->toDateTimeString();
        $end = Carbon\Carbon::parse($end)->toDateTimeString();
        // we receive some thing like:
        // Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
        $sales = Sale::with('SaleLine.lens','SaleLine.cadre','cli_sale')
                    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        for ($i=0; $i < count($sales); $i++) {
            $sales[$i]['client_name'] = $sales[$i]['cli_sale']['first_name'] . " " . $sales[$i]['cli_sale']['last_name'];
        }
        return response()->success(['sales'=>$sales]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply i really apreciat it , the problem that i found is that "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (GMT 01:00)) at position 39 (0): Double time specification"

Comment: @KhalidCHBAB have you tested it in your tinker?

Comment: Yes I did try it in psysh

Comment: @KhalidCHBAB Can you copy your code and add to your question?

Comment: @KhalidCHBAB I have edited your code and posted, can you check if you are again getting any error with it?

Answer (score 2):

On my server this works:

```
function gmt2mysql($gmt)
{
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($gmt));
}
```

and

> Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200

becomes

> 2019-04-10 22:00:00

which MySQL can understand. It is the DATETIME type.

Do check carefully if this actually does work for you. Working with time can be tricky.

Clearly it doesn't work on your server, so we have to be a bit more explicit. You could try this altenative:

```
function gmt2mysql($gmt)
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D M j Y H:i:s ???O", $gmt);
    $date->setTimezone(timezone_open('GMT'));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Here we make the assumption that the timezone offset in your dates will always be GMT. Is it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added this function but it always gives me this "1970-01-01 00:00:00" as a result? how come so?

Comment: It must be the `strtotime()` function not understanding the string. This could be due to your specific PHP version, I'm running 7.2.17, or the build. However, according to the manual this function hasn't changed since version 5.3.0. The manual says the alternative is to use [createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and return that.